# How to connect build agent to PostgreSQL database

Tags: azure-devops

My integration tests for my asp.net core application require a connection to a PostgreSQL database.  In my deployment pipeline I only want to deploy if my integration tests pass.

How do I supply a working connection string inside the Microsoft build agent?

I looked under service connections and couldn't see anything related to a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Microsoft hosted agent, then your database need to be accessible from internet.
Otherwise, you need to it on self-hosted agent that can access your database.

I assume the default connectionstring is in [appsettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/sql?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio), you could store the actual database connectionstring to a secret variable, then update appsettings.json file with that variable value through some task (e.g. [Set Json Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61628233/how-to-connect-build-agent-to-postgresql-database)) or do it programming (e.g. powershell script) before running web app and starting test during build.

If you can use any PostgreSQL database, you can use [service container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/service-containers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) with a docker image that has PostgreSQL database (e.g. [postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)).

For classical pipeline, you could call docker command run the image.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `runsettings` which you can override in task. In that way you will keep your connection string away of source control. Please check this [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/supplying-run-time-parameters-to-tests/). And in terms of service connection, you don't need any service connection, only what you need is proper connection string.

Since I don't know how you connect to your DB in details I can't give you more info. If you provide example how you already connect to database I can try to provide a better answer.